# How to create a multi-page PDF-file with Gnuplot?

Tags: ruby, pdf, gnuplot, multipage

I make a dozen of plots with Gnuplot on Mac via [ruby-gnuplot](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot). If I re-run my ruby script, then the number of open windows with the plots doubles. If I could just output all these plots in a PDF opened in Preview, then the file would be automatically updated after every re-run and I don't need to bother closing the numerous windows.

Currently I can achieve this only with one plot per PDF-file:

```
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
    plot.arbitrary_lines << "set terminal pdf \n set output 'figures.pdf'"
    # ...
  end
end
```

How can I make a single PDF with all my figures by Gnuplot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm, at least on gnuplot for UN*x, multipage output for postscript and PDF always was the default - as long as you don't either change the terminal type nor reassign the output file, everything you plot ends up on a new page.

I.e. you do:

```
set terminal pdf
set output "multipageplot.pdf"
plot x, x*x
plot sin(x), cos(x)
set output ""
```

and you end up with two pages in the PDF file, one containing line/parabola, the other sine/cosine.

To clarify: The important thing is to issue all the `plot` commands in sequence, without changing the output file nor changing the terminal type. Gnuplot won't append to an existing PDF file.

Comment: You are right - I was reassigning the output in between the plots. Thanks for opening my eyes!

Comment: I didn't get it. Where to set the terminal/output if using Ruby-Gnuplot?

Answer (score 0):

I make thousands of plots with ruby-gnuplot and use a gem called prawn to compile them into a pdf. The following is a code snippet using prawn, that includes some useful features:

```
require 'prawn'

def create_pdf
  toy_catalogue = @toy_catalogue
  full_output_filename ||= "#{output_path}/#{pre-specified_filename_string}"
  Prawn::Document.generate(full_output_filename, :page_layout => :portrait, :margin => 5, :skip_page_creation => false, :page_size => [595, 1000]) do
    toy_catalogue.each do |toy|
      start_new_page

      image toy[:plan_view], :at => [0,900], :width => 580

      image toy[:front_view], :at => [0, 500], :width => 585

      font_size(20) { draw_text toy[:name], :at => [5, 920] }

      draw_text "production_date = #{toy[:date]}", :at => [420, 930]
    end
  end
end
```

That should be easy enough to adapt to your purposes.