# How to combine the output of child scripts from the parent script in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, postscript

I have a parent gnuplot script that calls a child gnuplot script depending on certain conditions. I want to combine the output graphs of the child scripts into a single `.eps` file. How do I go about doing this?

As an example, my parent script is:

```
set terminal postscript
set output "combined.eps"    
if (there_is_s == 1) call "child.gplot" "0"
if (there_is_p == 1) call "child.gplot" "1"
```

Where `there_is_s` and `there_is_p` are conditions that I've defined earlier in the parent script.

My child script `child.gplot` is:

```
set terminal postscript
set output "child".ARG1.".eps"
#plot graph here
```

I basically want the 2 graphs of the child scripts into a combined `.eps` file, one on each page, while using this method it creates 5 different plots `child1.eps` etc.

I tried removing the option to set terminal as postscript in the child script, but that just gives me a single graph corresponding to `child0.eps`, while `child1.eps` is nowhere to be found. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a multi-page PDF-file with Gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334301/how-to-create-a-multi-page-pdf-file-with-gnuplot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have multiple pages in an EPS file. EPS graphics are intended for inclusion on a page, and as such they may not include the PostScript operator `showpage` which is used to end one page and start another.

So you either need to follow the URL in the comment from Wrzlpmft and create a PostScript file instead of an EPS (assuming gnuplot is capable of such a thing, the link is for PDF output), or you need to combine the EPS files yourself into a PostScript program.

If you want to do the latter then you need to read the DSC comments from the EPS files (lines beginning %%), find the BoundingBox comments, Insert ahead of the EPS a  requested media size for the area of the BoundingBox (using the `setpagedevice` operator), translate the EPS content onto the media if the lower left co-ordinate is not 0,0 (using the `translate` operator) and put a `showpage` after the EPS content. Then do the same with the second EPS file and concatenate the two results.